# Взять с начала строки до определенного места. findall()

Tags: python, python-3.x, re

Данный код находит значения между строк 1 и 3900. Мне же нужно собрать айпишники без порта, как это правильно сделать?

```
x="""
10.0.0.4:3900Test1
10.40.0.5:3900Test2
10.20.0.5:3900Test3
"""
print ([j for i,j in re.findall(r"( :3900 | 1 )\s*(.*?)\s*(?!\1)(? :1 | :3900 )",x)])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x="""
10.0.0.4:3900Test1
10.0.0.5:3900Test2
10.0.0.5:3900Test3
"""
res = ([j for i,j in re.findall(r"(:3900|\n)\s*(.*?)\s*(?!\1)(?: \n|:3900)",x)])
for elem in res:
    print(elem)
```

Нужно было искать новую строку \n.

Answer (score 0):

```
s='10.0.0.4:3900Test1'
s.split(':')
['10.0.0.4', '3900Test1']
```

Comment: Нужно получить все ип адреса, так оно мне вернуло: ['\n10.0.0.4', '3900Test1\n10.0.0.5', '3900Test2\n10.0.0.5', '3900Test3\n']

Comment: Я вам показал.как вернуть один ип адрес. Сделайте список и пройдитесь по нему циклом. Можно обойтись без регулярки